# Does a Virtual machine leverage the host machine's Cryptography API?

Tags: windows, encryption, tls1.2

I have a web client and server that are communicating using TLS 1.2 with the **TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384** cipher suite.

When running on a Windows 10 or Server 2016 machine, the handshake is successful. When running on a Windows 7 machine, the handshake is not successful (the cipher suite is not supported in Windows 7).

I am having a an issue with the handshake when running the client and server on a Server 2016 VM on the Windows 7 machine.

Is the VM using the host machine's cipher suites?

Comment: What virtual machine are you using (VMware, VirtualBox, etc)?  I would think that it wouldn't or at least ask in a similar fashion to asking to use the hosts CD player or other resources.

Comment: I am using virtual box